# <s:fileUpload> is returning null value

Tags: java, seam, seam2

while doing file upload  using `<s:fileUpload>` component is returning to null .

application is  using seam 2.1.2 integrate with Richfaces,Jsf

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"
   columnClasses="columnFull">
<s:fileUpload id="picture" data="#{image.uploadedFile}"

    contentType="#{image.pictureContentType}" />

</h:panelGrid>


@Name("image")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class DoImportServiceUpload {


      @Lob
      @Column(length = 2147483647)
      private  byte[] uploadedFile;

      private String pictureContentType;
```

}

web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

components.xml

```
<web:multipart-filter create-temp-files="true"
                      max-request-size="1000000" 
                      url-pattern="*.seam" />
```

Comment: Can you post the form in which the `<s:fileUpload/>` is embedded? Is it `<h:form />` or `<a4j:form/>`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Put a breakpoint in the Seam MultiPartFilter. Connect to your application server using remote debugging. Check whether the filter is actually fired, and whether it finds a file upload.
2. If not, the file upload is probably not present in the POST request. Check in Google Chrome whether a fileUpload is actually being sent using the correct content type.
3. Check whether the `s:fileUpload` tag is actually enclosed in a single `h:form`. The `h:form` should be of type `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">`. Check whether this is also correctly rendered in the HTML output.